# Problem using LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> with custom RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I have tried loading the list using the ListView along with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks and custom CursorAdapter and it works fine. But I am trying to accomplish the same using RecyclerView along with custom RecyclerView.Adapter but I am getting this issue:

I am getting the list displayed for the first time but when I rotate the device the list disappears.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code, please have a look.

**CatalogActivity**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int ITEMS_LOADER_ID = 1;
    public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_NAME = "extra_item_name";
    public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_STOCK = "extra_item_stock";

    @BindView(R.id.list_items)
    RecyclerView mListItems;

    private ItemAdapter mItemAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setupListItems();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(ITEMS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    private void setupListItems() {
        mListItems.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mListItems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mListItems.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mListItems.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
        mItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this);
        mListItems.setAdapter(mItemAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnClickItem(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.class);

        Item item = mItemAdapter.getItems().get(position);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_NAME, item.getName());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_STOCK, item.getStock());

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ArrayList<Item> getItems(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int columnIndexId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry._ID);
                int columnIndexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
                int columnIndexStock = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry.COLUMN_STOCK);

                int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndexId);
                String name = cursor.getString(columnIndexName);
                int stock = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(columnIndexStock));

                items.add(new Item(id, name, stock));
            }
        }

        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (loaderId) {
            case ITEMS_LOADER_ID: {
                String[] projection = {
                        ItemEntry._ID,
                        ItemEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                        ItemEntry.COLUMN_STOCK
                };

                return new CursorLoader(
                        this,
                        ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
            }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mItemAdapter.setItems(getItems(cursor));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Item> mItems;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        if (items != null) {
            mItems = items;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void OnClickItem(int position);
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.tv_item)
        TextView tv_item;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_stock)
        TextView tv_stock;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mOnItemClickListener.OnClickItem(position);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_inventory, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int position) {
        final Item item = mItems.get(position);

        itemViewHolder.tv_item.setText(item.getName());
        itemViewHolder.tv_stock.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.display_stock, item.getStock()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mItems == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return mItems.size();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the extact issue. Please help.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What disappears, exactly? The whole `RecyclerView`, or just the items? Have you checked that the `LoaderCallbacks` methods are running correctly upon rotation? Have you checked the delivered `Cursor`'s size and contents? Is the `ArrayList` being built?

Comment: @MikeM. The whole RecyclerView disappears obviously. Didn't you saw the screenshots above and the explanation along? I debugged and found that in `getItems()` method `while(cursor.moveToNext)` does not work after rotation. The loader methods are working fine.

Comment: Please explain exactly how it is obvious that the whole `RecyclerView` disappears. You make absolutely no mention of that, specifically, in your description, and the screenshots cannot convey that, since a transparent `RecyclerView` with no items looks exactly the same as no `RecyclerView` at all – a blank white box. I don't think that's actually what you mean, anyway.

Comment: Yes I did mentioned that the list disappears right before the screenshots - _I am getting the list displayed for the first time but when I rotate the device the **list disappears**._

Comment: Any link to the project? Github, etc...

Comment: That is vague and ambiguous, which is why I asked that in the first place. What is "list"? Is it the whole `RecyclerView` itself that doesn't show after rotation, or is it just that it doesn't have any items?

Comment: @MikeM. `while(cursor.moveToNext)` does not work even if the cursor not null and cursor count is > 0

Comment: @MikeM. That's ok. You got now! As I have stated in the above comments what I have debugged and found out  please help me with that. :)

Comment: Change that `if` to `if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())`, and then change the `while` to a `do-while`; i.e., move `while (cursor.moveToNext());` to after the loop body, and put `do` in front of the loop body.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeM. Yes this worked! :) And it preserves the scroll position also which is correct. Please post your answer so that I can mark it as correct and others including me can up vote. Would you please explain this while and do-while issue in detail? Why does this happens? Are there any other scenarios (examples) where developers need to take care of the situation like this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, good. I wasn't 100% certain that was it, and didn't have a chance to test it. It'll be a little bit before I'm able to post a full answer, but I'll give a short summary here, just so you know what's happening. A `Cursor` tracks its current position within its records. When you first start the app and the `Loader` is created, it grabs its `Cursor`, and then delivers it fresh to your `Activity` (the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`). At this point, its position is `-1`, so your loop using only `moveToNext()` works just fine. However, after rotation, the `Loader` already has its `Cursor`...

Comment: ...so it just immediately delivers that same one again. However, the position is still where you left it after the first time that `while` loop ran, which is at its end, so it couldn't `moveToNext()` from there. Our `moveToFirst()` call in the `if` positions it back at the beginning. The `do-while` adjustment is because `moveToFirst()` followed immediately by `moveToNext()` would skip the first record. Follow that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183417/discussion-between-vaibhav-dhunde-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, the issue here is that, after rotation, you're being handed the same `Cursor` that you had previously looped over before the rotation, but you're not accounting for its current position.

A `Cursor` tracks and maintains its own position within its set of records, as I'm sure you've gathered from the various `move*()` methods it contains. When first created, a `Cursor`'s position will be set to right before the first record; i.e., its position will be set to `-1`.

When you first start your app, the `LoaderManager` calls `onCreateLoader()`, where your  `CursorLoader` is instantiated, and then causes it to load and deliver its `Cursor`, with the `Cursor`'s position at `-1`. At this point, the `while (cursor.moveToNext())` loop works just as expected, since the first `moveToNext()` call will move it to the first position (index `0`), and then to each available position after that, until the end.

Upon rotation, however, the `LoaderManager` determines that it already has the requested `Loader` (determined by ID), which itself sees that it already has the appropriate `Cursor` loaded, so it just immediately delivers that same `Cursor` object again. (This is a major feature of the `Loader` framework – it won't reload resources it already has, regardless of configuration changes.) This is the crux of the issue. That `Cursor` has been left at the last position to which it was moved before the rotation; i.e., at its end. Consequently, the `Cursor` cannot `moveToNext()`, so that `while` loop just never runs at all, after the initial
 `onLoadFinished()`, before rotation.

The simplest fix, with the given setup, would be to manually reposition the `Cursor` yourself. For example, in `getItems()`, change the `if` to `moveToFirst()` if the `Cursor` is not null, and change the `while` to a `do-while`, so we don't inadvertently skip over the first record. That is:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    do {
        int columnIndexId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemEntry._ID);
        ...
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

With this, when that same `Cursor` object is re-delivered, its position is kinda "reset" to position `0`. Since that position is directly on the first record, rather than right before it (remember, initially `-1`), we change to a `do-while`, so that the first `moveToNext()` call doesn't skip the first record in the `Cursor`.

---

Notes:

- I would mention that it is possible to implement a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to take a `Cursor` directly, similar to the old `CursorAdapter`. In this, the `Cursor` would necessarily be moved in the `onBindViewHolder()` method to the correct position for each item, and the separate `ArrayList` would be unnecessary. It'd take a little effort, but translating [`CursorAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java) to a `RecyclerView.Adapter` isn't terribly difficult. Alternatively, there are certainly solutions already available.  (For example, possibly, [this one](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b), though I cannot vouch for it, atm, I often see a trusted fellow user recommend it often.)
- I would also mention that the native `Loader` framework has been [deprecated, in favor of the newer `ViewModel`/`LiveData` architecture framework in support libraries](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders). However, it appears that the newest androidx library has its own internal, improved `Loader` framework which is a simple wrapper around said `ViewModel`/`LiveData` setup. This seems to be a nice, easy way to utilize the known `Loader` constructs while still benefiting from the recent architecture refinements.

Comment: Yes, that's correct to use the latest things in android and I will come to it soon as I am learning basic building blocks of android now as a beginner :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LoaderManager.initLoader()` call `LoaderManager.restartLoader()`

Comment: I have tried using this. I check if the loader is null then I use `initLoader()` else `restartLoader()`. But this queries the data again which ultimately does not preserve the scroll position of the list. Please note! `restartLoader()` should be used if you are refreshing the list or trying to query some other list of data.